# iPhone X: Calculate perfect height of CollectionviewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, uikit

I have a collectionview covering the whole screen. I want to use the collectionview so that all cells are visible at the same time which means that the height gets set dynamically. And as a plus: It should work in portrait and landscape.

In the past I solved it like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
    {
        let heightOffset = (UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait) ? CGFloat(30) : CGFloat(0)

        let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height - heightOffset

        return CGSize(width: width, height: height / CGFloat(mainScreenItems.count))
    }
```

But on iPhoneX I get problems, because the offset is not correct. Even if I take the height of the collectionview frame it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: you might need to consider view.safeAreaInsets ?

Comment: not perfect, but better: heightOffset = superView.safeAreaInsets.top + superView.safeAreaInsets.bottom + collectionView.safeAreaInsets.top

Comment: if you use switch to safe area layout from normal auto layout, you might not have to do this :)